# Fetch all unique combinations with running total

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have say 5000 records in a table with 5 unique ClientId's. How can I select 100 records in which all 5 unique clientId's are covered also have running total column In SQL Server

I m able to select all uniques values but unable to add running total

For ex there are 5 unique names.

```
ClientId.    Name. Amt. runningtotal
5.                Abc.    10.    10
3.                Def.    20.    30
6.                Xxx.     5.    35
2.                You.    10.    45
1.                Fed.    20.    65
5.                Abc.     5.    70
3.                Def.    12.    82
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: please highlight your 5 unique names. with desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ClientId, Name, Amt, 
   SUM(Amt) OVER(ORDER BY ClientId 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
      AS RunningTotal
              FROM Table
```